# Ограничить количество символа JS

Tags: javascript, строки, функции, валидация

```js
let email = document.getElementById('email');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let emailCheck1 = function() {
  if (email5.value.indexOf('@', 0) < 1) {
    console.log('good');
  } else {
    console.log('wrong');
  }
}
emailCheck1()
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="button" value="register" id="btn">
```

Задача: нужно сделать валидацию поля не используя регулярные выражения. Валидация заключается в том чтобы можно было ставить @ только 1 раз и при нажатии на кнопку все это дело проверять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я исхожу из того, что нам нужно посчитать собак. Если одна, то строка поделится сплитом на 2. Если собак больше, то на 3 и более. Если поделенная сплитом строка 2 или меньше, то ок. Но тут, имхо, в этом варианте надо всё-таки не больше 2 проверять, а равно 2. Т.е. это имейл, и @ там должна быть в любом случае. Но всё-таки лучше регуляркой. На всякий случай тут её оставлю.

`let mailReg = /^[\w\-\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\.]+[^\.-]@([\w\-]+\.+)+([A-Za-z]+)$/;`

```js
let email = document.getElementById('email');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let emailCheck1 = function() {
  let symbs = email.value.split('@');
  if(symbs.length !== 2) {
    console.log('bad')
  } else {
    console.log('ok');
  }
  
}

btn.addEventListener('click', emailCheck1);
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="button" value="register" id="btn">
```

Comment: А как еще при такой валидации сделать так, чтобы когда в поле ноль собак выводило тоже 'bad'?

Comment: @ТемныйМаг изменил ответ. Проверяем на равенство двум, а не больше или меньше.

Answer (score 3):

```js
let email = document.getElementById('email');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let emailCheck1 = function() {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < email.value.length; i++) {
    if (email.value[i] == '@')
      count++;
    if (count > 1) {
      console.log('wrong');
      return;
    }
  }
  console.log('good');
}

email.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.key == '@') {
    if (this.value.indexOf('@') != -1) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="button" value="register" id="btn" onclick="emailCheck1()">
```